# how to set correct timestring in metricbeat index?

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat, elasticsearch-curator

I was trying to set a custom metricbeat index in elasticsearch indices.

When I add like below to metricbeat.yml file

```
        index: "metricbeat-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy-MM-dd}"
      setup.template:
        name: "metricbeat"
        pattern: "metricbeat-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy-MM-dd}"
```

The index generated is `metricbeat-7.8.0-2021.03.11-000001`. But the timestring `'%Y.%m.%d'` in curator is not matching it and not able to clear the indices.

How to make the index from `metricbeat-7.8.0-2021.03.11-000001` to `metricbeat-7.8.0-2021.03.11`?

I even tried like this

```
        index: "metricbeat-{now/d}"
      setup.template:
        name: "metricbeat"
        pattern: "metricbeat-{now/d}"
```

But same patter of index. Please help with this.

Update:

Curator config

```
Data
====
action_file.yml:
----
---
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: "Clean up ES by deleting old indices"
    options:
      timeout_override:
      continue_if_exception: False
      disable_action: False
      ignore_empty_list: True
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: regex
      value: '^(metricbeat-).*$'
    - filtertype: age
      source: name
      direction: older
      timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
      unit: days
      unit_count: 7
      field:
      stats_result:
      epoch:
      exclude: False
config.yml:
----
---
client:
  hosts:
    - elasticsearch-master.paas.svc
  port: 9200
  # url_prefix:
  # use_ssl: True
  # certificate:
  # client_cert:
  # client_key:
  # ssl_no_validate: True
  # http_auth:
  # timeout: 30
  # master_only: False
logging:
  loglevel: DEBUG
#   logfile:
#   logformat: default
#   blacklist: ['elasticsearch', 'urllib3']
```

Comment: Perhaps if you shared what you're trying to use in Curator I could help make it work?

Comment: Was trying to clear metricbeat indices using curator. But the indices are not getting cleared.

Comment: Please let me clarify: I need to know what your Curator configuration looks like in order to help. This is what I meant by "what you're trying to use in Curator."

Comment: I have edited the question with config.

Answer (score 0):

The index pattern `metricbeat-7.8.0-2021.03.11-000001` indicates that metricbeat is using rollover indices. It is affixing the date when the index was created, and an incrementing number. This also means that you likely have an ILM policy affixed to your rollover indices. As such, you should read about [ILM *and* Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.8/ilm-and-curator.html) in the documentation. To correct these indices being filtered, you have to add [`allow_ilm_indices: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.8/option_allow_ilm.html) to the `options` in your configuration.